# How to set offline a user of my db when session expires

Tags: php, sql, logout

I have a logout script that set offline to the status of the user that is connect to my website  when he clicks the logout link. I know that after some time if the user does nothing, the user disconnect him. How can i set the status offline when the session expires? Because now if the user close the tab of the website or close the browser directly the status in the db still remains online despite it's not .

Here's the logout.php script

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
include 'db_connect.php';

sec_session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$queryoffline="UPDATE User SET status='offline' WHERE username='$username';";
$ris_queryoffline=mysqli_query($conn,$queryoffline);

// Delete every session value.
$_SESSION = array();
// Gather session's parameters.
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
// Delete actual cookies.
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
// Delete the session.

session_destroy();
header('Location: ./index.php');
?>
```

And here is my session_start function, which rigenerate the session each time the user visit a page

```
function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Session name
        $secure = false; // True if using https
        $httponly = true; // This makes not possible to a js to go inside the session id 
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Force session to use cookies
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Read cookie's parameters
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        session_name($session_name); // Set session name with the choosen
        session_start(); // Avvia la sessione php.
        session_regenerate_id(); // Regenerate the session and delete the old 
}
```

Comment: You should check expiration directly by session not by db

Comment: It's what i'm trying to do. I just would to set offline the status in the db after check the effective expiration of the session

Answer (score 4):

You should probably not save the status as "offline" or "online" in your database, but instead the last time the user did something.

Inside of `sec_session_start()`, add something like this :

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE User SET last_action=NOW() WHERE username='$username';");
```

Once you have that, you can list all the users having `last_action > NOW() - [some_duration]`, based on what "online" means on your server (typically, `last_action > NOW() - one hour`).

Comment: +1. This answer tells me there's another native _clean_ way rather than "use web socket to handle  the event" at all

Comment: The problem is that as you can see, i haven't already the username of the user when i use sec_session_start(). It's just a session_start(), i haven't the credentials of the User in it.

Comment: You should put this UPDATE somewhere else then, as soon as you have the username in the code flow.